# Divide MDF in two disks

Tags: sql-server

Actually, I have a database on the `D:` drive, now there is no more free space on that disk.

Is there a way to keep this database on `D:` and create another, secondary database on another disk? So in this way I read data from two disks, is it possible ? I am working with SQL Server 2008.

Comment: A secondary database? Are you wanting to create a new database and have the files be on a drive other than D? Or are you trying to create multiple files for the existing database and have some on D and some on another drive?

Comment: yes when we attached file on the below section you can specify the path of your file

Comment: Look into file Groups (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms179316(v=SQL.105).aspx) You can create multiple file groups, choose a location for different file groups, then choose which tables belong in which file group. Youll have to look into how to move tables between file groups. This gives a complete answer for a large number of tables (http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16708/moving-large-number-of-tables-to-different-filegroupshttp://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16708/moving-large-number-of-tables-to-different-filegroups)